# How to extract data from a function to global scope

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

This problem is probably very easy to solve. I just can't seem to solve it. I currently have two functions, and I have to get the data out to the global object, but due to the syntax I'm unfamiliar with how to extract it. The following returns the value I'm looking for.

```
function position(func) {
    return window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(func);
}

position(pos => {
    console.log(pos.coords.latitude);
});
```

What I need to do is get this out to the global scope. One of my many attempts is the following, which shows up as `undefined`.

```
function position(func) {
    return window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(func);
}

let lat;

position(pos => {
    lat = pos.coords.latitude;
});

console.log(lat);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need it in a global scope? getCurrentPosition is asynchronous, so whatever code is depending on this value will need to use callbacks or promises one way or another.

Comment: `window.lat = pos.coords.latitude;` try this

Comment: I need it in a global scope in order to place the data into an action for react-redux. When I formatted it as an action by itself I used async/await in an exported variable. it. It turns out I still need to extract the data and I opted to make it a global variable. Would you like to see that attempt?

Comment: @IvanKaraman I renamed `lat` to `window.lat` within the position function and it still turns up as undefined. Am I assigning that to the wrong variable?